# vim strange behavior on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: vim

My installation of vim is behaving strangely (which I suspect started happening after I upgraded the distribution to 16.04 from 14.04).

The issue is that whenever I open a file vim edits it and replaces the first character with a `g`. For example if I have a file `foo.txt` with content:

```
stack
over
flow
```

And if I open the file with `$ vim foo.txt`, vim opens it with content:

```
gtack
over
flow
```

Note that I already reinstalled vim and it didn't help.

Comment: Could you post your ~/.vimrc file?

Comment: @mosh442 this vim installation is not using a .vimrc, so file is absent.

Comment: what is the output of `which vim`

Comment: @Kent `/usr/bin/vim`

Comment: Is the file also marked as changed, or is this a purely visual issue? In other words, does `:redraw` help? What's the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: @IngoKarkat The file changes. I can't do a `:q`. I have to first undo with `u` to bring it back to original state.

Comment: @IngoKarkat `:redraw` doesn't seem to change anything either. `:scriptnames` returns a list of 18 file paths in `/usr/share/vim`. Would you like me to post the paths?

Comment: I was checking for any non-default customizations. The stuff in `/usr/share/vim` should be fine. My next guess would be the terminal, that Vim receives anything containing `rg`, for example. What's your terminal and value of `$TERM`, then? (And does the problem also occur in `gvim`?)

Comment: @IngoKarkat It appears to be ssh client problem. I am using MobaXterm to connect to the machine. Apparently as I switched to a different client (git bash) the behavior disappeared. I need to check my MobaXterm installation. Thanks for your tip on checking the terminal.

Comment: I may still have to troubleshoot further as vim instance on other VM (Ubuntu 14.04) appears to work fine even if MobaXterm is used as the ssh client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tips from Ingo Karkat I was able to figure out that this was a problem with the version of ssh client (MobaXterm) I was using.

As I updated the client to 9.4, the normal behavior has been restored.